# select two columns if given condition is met, otherwise select another two columns

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql query

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS freq, column_name FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE() GROUP BY column_name;
Empty set (0.41 sec)
```

In this case when the results are empty I would like to return 0 for both columns so the result should be this:

```
+--------+------------+
| freq   | column_name|
+--------+------------+
|      0 |       0    |
+--------+------------+
```

I've tried following approaches but none of them worked as expected:

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*) AS freq, 0), IFNULL(column_name, 0) FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE() GROUP BY column_name;
Empty set (0.40 sec)


mysql> SELECT IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*), column_name FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE() GROUP BY column_name), 'not found');
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)


mysql> SELECT CASE WHEN ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE()) > 0 )
            THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS freq, column_name FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE() GROUP BY column_name)
            ELSE (SELECT 0,0) END;
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)


mysql> SELECT IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE()) > 0,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS freq, column_name FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE() GROUP BY column_name),
    (SELECT 0,0)
    );
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Could you create a fiddle, that will help to test answers: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can use the trick with union:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS freq, column_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE created_time >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY column_name
UNION
SELECT 0,0
FROM dual
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE created_time >= CURDATE()) = 0
```

I hope that someone suggests more elegant way to do this